# Why are my strings messed up on the 0th index in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a small game based on writing. I get my texts from text files. The content of these files is then parsed to List of Strings.

The strings get uploaded fine. But the problem occurs when printing out. The first sentence is always fine, but from the second the first letter is always wrong. It always follows a weird pattern for [0] index:

sentence1 [sentence1]

sentence2 [sentence1]

sentence3 [sentence2]

the first sentence works as it should:
[![properly working first sentence image][1]][1]

but the problem comes with the second sentence, from here it's messed up:

[![messed up writing out image][2]][2]

I thought that something was wrong with the script. But it doesn't seem like it.

```cs
public class WriteTextProlog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string givenSentence;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text textArea;
    [SerializeField] private float writeOutDelay;
    private float _writeCounter;
    private int _position;
    [SerializeField] private WriteOutSentences writeOutSentences;
    
    protected void Update()
    {
        if (!writeOutSentences.writeNewSentence)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_writeCounter < writeOutDelay)
        {
            
            _writeCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            return;
        }
        
        if (_position >= givenSentence.Length)
        {
            writeOutSentences.writeNewSentence = false;
            writeOutSentences.interactText.textForInteraction = givenSentence;
            writeOutSentences.ableToWriteInto = true;
            _position = 0;
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log(givenSentence);
        textArea.text += givenSentence[_position++];
        writeOutSentences.ableToWriteInto = false;    
        _writeCounter = 0f;
        

    }
    
}
```

But it doesn't seem like it. Because if I copy the object and delete it, the new object behaves as it should. But only for one run. It breaks also if I only go to a different scene.
But the weirdest thing is that I use this object (which is a prefab) across multiple levels. And it breaks on some levels more, on some it works on 90%.

Whole WriteOutSentences:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.Serialization;

public class WriteOutSentences : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent successfulInteraction;
    [SerializeField] private WriteTextProlog writeText;
    [SerializeField] public InteractTextPrologWritingSentences interactText;
    
    [Header("File")]
    private readonly List<string> _sentenceList = new();
    [SerializeField] private TextAsset myFile;
    private int _numberOfSentences;
    public bool interacting;
    
    [Header("Text fields")]
    [SerializeField] public TMP_Text ownTextField;
    [SerializeField] public WritingGameplayProlog writing;
    
    public int rowIndex;
    public bool writeNewSentence;
    public bool ableToWriteInto;
    


    private void Start()
    {
        LoadStrings();
        _numberOfSentences = _sentenceList.Count;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        
        if (!interacting)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        if (!writeNewSentence)
        {
            return;
        }

       
        if (rowIndex < _numberOfSentences)
        {
            writeText.givenSentence = _sentenceList[rowIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            writing.controlWordsProlog.canMove = true;
            Destroy(gameObject); 
        }

        

    }
    
    private void LoadStrings()
    {
        var textFromFile = myFile.ToString(); //gets contents of file
        var lines = textFromFile.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (!line.Equals(""))
            {
                _sentenceList.Add(line);
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        interacting = true;
        writing.controlWordsProlog.stopWritingTimer = true;
        writing.controlWordsProlog.canMove = false;
        writing.ChangeTextArea(ownTextField);
        writeNewSentence = true;
        interactText.interactable = true;
    }

    public int ReturnNumOfLines()
    {
        return _sentenceList.Count;
    }
}
```

Increesing rowIndex in InteractTextPrologWritingSentences

```cs
public class InteractTextPrologWritingSentences : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string textForInteraction;
    [SerializeField] private WritingGameplayProlog writing;
    [SerializeField] private WriteOutSentences writeOutSentences;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text textArea;
    public bool interactable;
    
    private enum ReturnMeanings {EmptyWord, NotMatchingLetter, MatchingLetter};
    
    
    private void Update()
    {

        if (!interactable)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        
        if (!writeOutSentences.ableToWriteInto)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        
        
        var result = CheckIndexes(writing.ReturnText());
        
        switch (result)
        {
            case (int)ReturnMeanings.EmptyWord:
                return;
            case (int)ReturnMeanings.NotMatchingLetter:
                writing.ClearText();
                break;
        }
        
        if (writing.ReturnText().Equals(textForInteraction))
        {
            writing.ClearText();
            textArea.text = "";
            writeOutSentences.writeNewSentence = true;
            writeOutSentences.rowIndex++;
            
        }
        
    }
    

    private int CheckIndexes(string textFromField)
    {
        if (textFromField.Length == 0)
        {
            return (int) ReturnMeanings.EmptyWord;
        }
        
        if (textFromField.Length > textForInteraction.Length)
        {
            return (int)ReturnMeanings.NotMatchingLetter;
        }
        
        for (var i = 0; i < textFromField.Length; i++)
        {
            if (textFromField[i] != textForInteraction[i])
            {
                return (int)ReturnMeanings.NotMatchingLetter;
            }
        }
        
        return (int)ReturnMeanings.MatchingLetter;
    }
}
```

Added checks to lastsentence and rowIndex

```cs
public class WriteTextProlog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string givenSentence;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text textArea;
    [SerializeField] private float writeOutDelay;
    private float _writeCounter;
    private int _position;
    [SerializeField] private WriteOutSentences writeOutSentences;
    private int _lastRowIndex;
    private string _lastSentence;

    private void Start()
    {
        _lastSentence = "";
        _lastRowIndex = -1;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!writeOutSentences.writeNewSentence)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_writeCounter < writeOutDelay)
        {
            
            _writeCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            return;
        }

        if (_lastRowIndex == writeOutSentences.rowIndex)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        
        if (_position >= givenSentence.Length)
        {
            _lastRowIndex = writeOutSentences.rowIndex;
            _lastSentence = givenSentence;
            writeOutSentences.writeNewSentence = false;
            writeOutSentences.interactText.textForInteraction = givenSentence;
            writeOutSentences.ableToWriteInto = true;
            _position = 0;
            
            return;
        }

        if (_lastSentence.Equals(givenSentence))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        Debug.Log(givenSentence);
        Debug.Log(_position +":" + givenSentence[_position] + ":"+(writeOutSentences.rowIndex));
        
        textArea.text += givenSentence[_position++];
        writeOutSentences.ableToWriteInto = false;    
        _writeCounter = 0f;
        

    }
    
}
```

Comment: From experience, whenever someone says "I have this flow, it has 9 steps, but on step 7 there are problems A and B... I know 100% that steps 1-6 are fine, look at step 7, that is the problem" in at least half of them the problem is before where they say it is. Please consider looking how the texts are parsed, the list is built and all the other steps up to the listing on the text field. Now, I know you said *The strings get uploaded fine*, but we don't see that. And from past experience, I like to cover all bases just to be extra sure. When you say it breaks on other levels, how do you mean?

Comment: What about `WriteOutSentences`, can we see it, or are you too sure it's absolutely fine? Also the logic is quite strange to me, why not just use a `Coroutine` which simply enumerates through every letter, writes it to the `Input Field` and returns a delay?

Comment: @TheNomad I tried looking everywhere. Checked how the strigs are being parsed. That's why I log out the GivenSentence - to check if it's all right. I also checked if the positions are indexed from 0 on every run.
What I mean that it breaks also on other levels - this issue is consistent through out levels. I have it as a prefab. But not all of them break. Some behave like they should. And some break.

Comment: @IDBB just uploaded the whole script. I will try putting it whole into Coroutine, thank you for the idea.

Comment: I am sorry, but I find this code really hard to read. Can't this be done with one simple `Coroutine` which writes sentences / characters with a delay? I wonder whether you need so much useless code to implement it.

Comment: @IDBB There's too much obsession with CoRoutines. You don't need to always use CoRoutines and it's not hard  to read at all. Time stepping is fine, it's how every other app (including games) do it when there are no CoRoutines in a language. With deltaTime, instead of yield, it's just a `-=` or `+=` (depending whether you step up or down) and a return. Sorry to be direct, but the fact that *you* find it hard to read, doesn't make it *useless code*. There are some things that need to be improved for sure, but I would focus on teaching him best practices not to make it easier for *me* to read it.

Comment: @LoadingError404 Some caveats for you in `WriteOutSentences `. Don't put `SerializeField` on `internal` or `public` variables. You made `_sentenceList` as `readonly` but you modify it in `LoadStrings()` which I find a strange pattern. `readonly` is mostly for immutable data. Why did you use it there? Next, You added `interacting` and `writeNewSentence`. Why? You can just use `enabled` which does what you want, including "disabling" `Update()` calls and both of your vars seem to be used (almost) identically. Similar curiosity about `ableToWriteInto`. Keep them in mind if you want to simplify :)

Comment: @LoadingError404 Let's see if I got this. Is the writing on the screen letter by letter, typewriter style? Also, where do you increase `rowIndex`?

Comment: @TheNomadyes, you are right. The text is first printed out from a file letter by letter and then the player needs to write that text letter by letter.
I increase this index in player controller when the right text is written. I also noticed that this script breaks even when not using character controler.

Comment: also thank you @TheNomad for the nice ideas. With the readonly thing, Raider suggested it to me. I also found it strange but it seems like it works (which I know that is a bad thing in coding just to keep something because it works somehow). The `interacting` is true when a player is in a collision with the parent object and the `writeNewSentence` is triggered once an interaction (writing the text right) is successful. It could be definitely done through a function.

Comment: @LoadingError404 Please show the code where you increase `rowIndex`. All its references if you can (reset to 0 or -1 or other values, its increase, decrease, as well as the logic for calling them). I think we're getting close to the issue :)

Comment: @LoadingError404 As for that `readonly`, I wouldn't keep it in this situation. Regarding the multiple variables, as I said, I would just use `enabled`, not necessarily a function. But, just keep them in mind. If you will refactor the code, please **ALWAYS** backup everything before and work on the copy.  Don't rely on CTRL+Z. Trust me, I learned that the hard way years ago. Now I always make 2 backups, since sometimes when trying to rollback code to the original I forget I am in the backup and modify the backup as well when I am in a hurry on a tight deadline :( Even I am not perfect :)

Comment: @TheNomad added the code that increases `rowIndex`. It increases if the string that the player puts in matches the text for interaction.
Regarding having backups, I use Git so I have it. The problem is that I was working on other parts (because at that point the code worked fine) and didn't realise that it broke some day. It was a mistake not to check it regularly and I've learned from it.

Comment: I have a feeling this is the culprit, since from then on you just concatenate the next sentence. My guess is position 0 uses the old rowIndex (so the previous sentence's first letter), you advance the row to get to the new sentence and advance the position, thus continuing with the new sentence from the second letter. Can you please check if this is the case?

Comment: @TheNomad I tested your thesis. I did it by Logging out when I increased `rowIndex` and also each letter. `rowIndex` was increased first. Only after that the letters were printed out. Weird thing is that it didn't print out the first letter

Comment: Don't test it on the first try as the default of ints is 0. Test it on the executions with problems, like when it's reset or broken and then after test it when it works. I think we're close, if you say that the first letter wasn't printed as it's the same behavior with the exception that the "normal" wrong behavior in your post says it displays the "old" first letter. If you tried it on the first execution, the "old" first letter is nothing which would be why it didn't print the first one. Yes, it is a guess as I can't test your workflow fully, but I am thinking of a way.

Comment: @TheNomad I tried something
` Debug.Log(givenSentence);
        Debug.Log(_position +":" + givenSentence[_position] + ":"+(writeOutSentences.rowIndex));`

but they were outputted in the opposite order. first was written out the bad letter and after that the sentence
I don't get it

Comment: Ah so seems I was right :) This would be consistent with what I said and you describe of "old" first letter + new rest of sentence.

Comment: @TheNomad you were right. And because of this, I was able to fix it. Not by the most elegant solution but it works. If I wasn't in a time clutch, I would recode it. But now it works! I just added checks if the row and sentence were changed. Because from what I can see there is some delay before the new sentence is changed. Thank you so much for your help. You saved me. And thank you for your patience. You are the best

Comment: I'm glad I could help! And if I helped you learn something from this and how to track causes of bugs I am even happier as the main purpose of this is that you learn. I will only end with this: please write TODOs: my suggestions from earlier comments and this refactoring of the fix and keep them for a game update patch (remember to test it before release). The key idea behind it is while it *works*, the best is to write proper and clean code. Obviously, permanently updating and optimizing instead of doing new things is not good either, so a key balance is needed. Good luck with your projects!

Comment: One more thing: don't take this a wrong way, but the cause of the bug might be bad design architecture of the classes and code. For example, if you control 5 different classes via `Update()` and restrict execution with `if -> return` statements, it is impossible to know the order they run in, so frames might be skipped if your *if* conditions are not met which would have an impact in how your game runs. Also take a lesson from this to improve the design on future games. Trust me, we've all been there. That is how you learn. Nobody had a perfect project from day 1, no matter what they say :)

Comment: @TheNomad thank you for your kind words. I added your suggestions into To do list. Thank you so much